# How to add commas to numbers in facebook fans php code?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I am using the following code to output my Facebook page fans:

```
$page_id = "139640489559144";
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
    $fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
echo $fans;
```

This outputs the number of fans like this:
170865

And I would like it to output like this:
170,865

Any easy way to accomplish this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wait. FQL is going to be deprecated very soon. Please use Facebook Graph API instead.

Comment: Does my answer bellow helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) function:

```
$page_id = "139640489559144";
$xml = @simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
$fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
echo number_format($fans);
```

As explained in the doc, if only one parameter is given, number will be formatted without decimals, but with a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

Comment: Ouch. Why so complicated? `number_format($fans)` will work fine.